# Finding an idempotent that satisfies certain conditions in a matrix ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

I've been stuck on a problem, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out. The problem is:

> Let $R$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix ring over the reals $\mathbb{R}$ of the form
>   $$ \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\0 & c\end{bmatrix}, $$
>   where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Find an idempotent $e$ in $R$ such that $eRe$ is a field, but the right ideal $eR$ is not minimal.

I was thinking of using $e=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, which is idempotent.
I also showed $eRe$ is a field, but I'm not sure how to show the right ideal $eR$ is not minimal.

If this $e$ doesn't work, I also tried $e=\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, but once again, I'm not sure how to show $eR$ is not minimal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last $e$ works:
$$
e=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $eRe$ consists of the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, so it is a field.

We have
$$
eR=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ a,b\in R\}
$$
is a right ideal, and it contains the right ideal
$$
J=\{\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ b\in R\}.
$$
As $J\subsetneq eR$, $eR$ cannot be minimal as a right ideal.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was simple, but I Wasn't seeing it.